# Ubuntu Core 18 on Raspberry Pi Screen Resolution

Tags: hdmi

My screen, after set up, is 800x600 (i guess) or just 4:3. I'm using HDMI on 42" tv that's touch enabled. How do I set the resolution to display correctly? This will be used for a "Your Are Here" interactive display, btw.
Using Ubuntu Core 18 on Raspberry Pi 3 b+.